# mvc web service does not work in azure but local

Tags: json, azure, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a web api with azure sql and i want to deploy it in the azure cloud. My service works in local so connection string is true but it does not work in the azure after deployment.

**My routeConfig;**

```
 routes.MapRoute("data", "data/{double1}/{double2}/{double3}", new { controller = "controllername", action = "methodname" });
```

and the web result after deployment

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found for this to work is to log into the Azure Preview Portal view, go to your App's blade, click on the link just below "API App Host". When that blade shows, then click on the Settings icon. In the Settings blade that displays click on Application Settings. Within the Web App Settings blade, there is a section called "App Settings". Enter your configuration settings here.